# PowerShell Enter Session find path bug

Tags: powershell, remote-access

I have some automation scripts, but I had to split them down because of what appears to be an interesting bug. I've stripped it to its simplest form below:

```
Enter-PSSession [SERVER]
cd D:\
```

If I run the above in one go, I get the below error

```
cd : Cannot find drive. A drive with the name 'D' does not exist.
```

However, if I run the lines individually, they run fine. I have tried putting a sleep in for a second, a pause line, but still no luck. Is anyone else aware of this, and the way around it?

Comment: `Enter-PSSession` is designed for _interactive_ use, don't use it in scripts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Invoke-Command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Core/Invoke-Command) instead of `enter-pssession`.

Example:

```
$ReturnValue = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Server -ScriptBlock{
    Set-Location D:
    # DO STUFF
    Return $ReturnValue # Return your stuff
}
```