# PowerShell "=" not a recognised cmdlet error

Tags: powershell, invoke-command, scriptblock

Further to the response given here: *[PowerShell Enter Session find path bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45957307/powershell-enter-session-find-path-bug/45958080#45958080)*, I've hit another wall in my script that I can't work around. The below script returns the error:

> The term '=' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

```
$sb = [ScriptBlock]::Create(@"
$Acl = (Get-Item -path D:\Websites\$Sitename).GetAccessControl('Access')
$Ar = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule('BUILTIN\IIS_IUSRS', 'Modify', 'ContainerInherit,ObjectInherit', 'None', 'Allow')
$Acl.SetAccessRule($Ar)
Set-Acl -path $Path -AclObject $Acl
"@)

Invoke-Command -Session $Session -ScriptBlock $sb
```

I can create the script block variable ($sb), but when I invoke it, I get the error. I have narrowed it down to the setting of the `$Acl` variable, and tried rewriting various ways with no luck. What am I missing?

Comment: Change `@""@` to `@''@` (single-quoted here strings rather than double-quoted)

Comment: That won't work as the $sitename variable is being passed into the script block, so needs to be expanded? I need the $acl, $ar $acl and $path variables to be handled as variables, but have the $sitename variable expanded

Comment: I've updated my answer to accommodate that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use a double-quoted here-string, it behaves just like a regular double-quoted string - the parser will evaluate and expand any variable or sub-expression between the quotation marks.

Since the variables in the scriptblock definition doesn't already exist in the defining context, you end up with a scriptblock with the following definition:

```
 = (Get-Item -path D:\Websites\).GetAccessControl('Access')
 = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule('BUILTIN\IIS_IUSRS', 'Modify', 'ContainerInherit,ObjectInherit', 'None', 'Allow')
.SetAccessRule()
Set-Acl -path  -AclObject
```

As you can see, the first two statements start out with just a bare `=` as the first non-whitespace character, and this is the reason for the error you're seeing.

Switch to a single-quoted here-string instead:

```
$sb = [ScriptBlock]::Create(@'
$Acl = (Get-Item -path D:\Websites\$Sitename).GetAccessControl('Access')
$Ar = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule('BUILTIN\IIS_IUSRS', 'Modify', 'ContainerInherit,ObjectInherit', 'None', 'Allow')
$Acl.SetAccessRule($Ar)
Set-Acl -path $Path -AclObject $Acl
'@)
```

If you need to pass in a variable value from the defining scope, I'd suggest either defining a `param` block in the scriptblock:

```
$sb = [ScriptBlock]::Create(@'
param($Sitename)
$Acl = (Get-Item -path D:\Websites\$Sitename).GetAccessControl('Access')
$Ar = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule('BUILTIN\IIS_IUSRS', 'Modify', 'ContainerInherit,ObjectInherit', 'None', 'Allow')
$Acl.SetAccessRule($Ar)
Set-Acl -path $Path -AclObject $Acl
'@)
 Invoke-Command -Session $Session -ScriptBlock $sb -ArgumentList $Sitename
```

or use the `-f` string format operator to replace it in the string before creating the scriptblock:

```
$sb = [ScriptBlock]::Create(@'
$Acl = (Get-Item -path D:\Websites\{0}).GetAccessControl('Access')
$Ar = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule('BUILTIN\IIS_IUSRS', 'Modify', 'ContainerInherit,ObjectInherit', 'None', 'Allow')
$Acl.SetAccessRule($Ar)
Set-Acl -path $Path -AclObject $Acl
'@ -f $Sitename)
```

---

See the [`about_Quoting_Rules` help topic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules) for more information about quoting and variable expansion

Comment: That's worked perfectly, thank you very much. i wasn't aware of the -f switch

Comment: @Karl It's referred to as the format operator in case you google it in the future.